# Mysql select data between four dates rang

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with a sql query

Please see this screenshot

[image: data]

I want to select data from this two rangs.

Date from 1996-07-04 to 1996-07-08 (rang 1)

and also from 1996-07-15 to 1996-07-18 (rang 2)

this two rangs has multiple data on table but its return null.

Mysql sql  query :

`SELECT * FROM Orders where OrderDate >= '1996-07-04' and OrderDate <= '1996-07-08' and OrderDate >= '1996-07-15' and OrderDate <= '1996-07-18';`

its return null.

I want to select data from this rangs.

Comment: A side note: Both question and answer have a strange casing in the query that doesn't make sense. Usually, queries are written completely in lower case OR the SQL key words are upper case and the rest is lower case. Here, none of these two options has been done.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the logical error Try using this:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders where 
(OrderDate >= '1996-07-04' and OrderDate <= '1996-07-08') 
or (OrderDate >= '1996-07-15' and OrderDate <= '1996-07-18');
```

Comment: Your query just return value from one rang (1996-07-04 to 1996-07-08) only. Your query do not return value from 2nd rang(1996-07-15 to 1996-07-18). I want to select data between two rangs.

Comment: It Should work but you can try between also,
SELECT * FROM Orders where 
    (OrderDate between '1996-07-04' and '1996-07-08') 
    or (OrderDate between '1996-07-15' and '1996-07-18');

Comment: If it doesn't return data for the second range, that's because your table doesn't contain such data or you failed to use correct data types for your date column.

Comment: Thanks all dear. Its work now. specially a warm heart thank to @ashutosh-sharma Ashutosh sharma. You are really helpful bro.